# Prove that $d(x,y)$ is a metric of $Y$ and describe the ball $B(x_{0},1)$

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

Let $X$ be the set of all bounded sequences and has the operations $x+y = \{x_{n}+y_{n}\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ and $\alpha x = \{\alpha x_{n}\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$. Let $Y=\{x\in X:\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}|x_{n}|$ exists$\}$ be a subspace of $X$.

Prove that $d(x,y)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}|x_{n}-y_{n}|$ is a metric of $Y$ and describe the ball $B(x_{0},1)$, where $x_{0}=\{0_{n}\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$

Now I already proved that $d(x,y)$ is a metric of $Y$ but I'm not sure if it's ok:

First I need to prove that $d(x,y)\geq 0$ $\forall x,y\in Y$, we can see this because of the absolute value, thus $|x_{n}-y_{n}|\geq 0$ $\forall n\in \mathbb{N}$, then $d(x,y)\geq 0$

Then we need to prove tha $d(x,y)=0 \Leftrightarrow x=y$, so because of the absolute value we have that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}|x_{n}-y_{n}|=0\Leftrightarrow|x_{n}-y_{n}|=0$ $\forall n\in \mathbb{N}$, thus $x=y$

Then we need to prove that $d(x,y)=d(y,x)$ which is easy to see because of the absolute value

For the last part we need to see that $d(x,y)\leq d(x,z)+d(z,y)$, in this part, since we have the absolute value we can say that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}|x_{n}-y_{n}|=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}|x_{n}-z_{n}+z_{n}-y_{n}|\leq \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}|x_{n}-z_{n}|+|z_{n}-y_{n}|=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}|x_{n}-z_{n}|+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}|z_{n}-y_{n}|$

Which means that $d(x,y)$ is in fact a metric of $Y$, Is this proof right?

Now for the ball, if I use the definition of a ball we have that $B(x_{0},1)=\{y_{n} \in Y:d(y,x_{0})\leq 1\}$, using our metric we have that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}|x_{0}-y_{n}|\leq1$ since $x_{0}$ is the constant sequence $0$ we can say that this is similar to $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}|y_{n}|\leq1$. So this is our ball, right? Is the sum of the absolute value of all bounded sequences less or equal then $1$?

Sorry for the long question and thanks for your help :)

Comment: Strange question.  One can only write down the definition of the ball. It doesn't make sense to ask how it looks like.

Comment: Sorry, maybe my english is not the best, maybe the word that I'm looking for is "describe"

Comment: The proof for the $1$-st part that $d(x,y)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{|x_{n}-y_{n}| }$ is a metric is correct for me but in the first place you need to show $d(x, y) $ is a  real number . i.e.  $d(x, y) <\infty$ and the $B(0, 1) $ is also okay.But, choose $x_n=\{1,1,1,0,0, ...\}$ a bounded sequence whose sum is $3$ not less than Or equal to $1$

Comment: Thanks, and sorry to ask but why do I need show that $d(x,y)$ is a real number? the distance is taking objects from $Y$ so it basically means that $d(x,y)<\infty$ almost by definition

Comment: @AlejandroL.g$:$ $d(x,y) \lt \infty$ is obvious since $x,y \in Y = \ell^1$ and $d$ is the metric induced by the $\ell^1$-norm; triangle inequality does the trick.

Comment: In fact you can try to prove the general result by showing that the metric induced by the norm in a normed linear space is a valid metric (i.e. it satisfies non-negativity, symmetry and triangle inequality). Consequently normed linear spaces are metric spaces in particular.

Comment: And, as far as the ball is concerned $B(x_0,1) = \{y \in Y\ |\ \|y\|_1 \leq 1\}.$

Comment: @AlejandroL.g  here $d(x, y) <\infty$ is obvious because $|x_n -y_n|\le |x_n|+|y_n|$ but in general you need to verify $d(x, y) \in [0, \infty) $ and you can't use "the distance is taking objects from Y" in the first place because "distance" make sense only $d$ is a metric .

Comment: Thank you everyone for your comment and your help :), so I’m not wrong but I can prove a better general result